# command for list users in linux system

Tags: linux, ldap, users, nis

How can i list all the linux users when the ldap autentication is cofigured? I remember that there are one command to list the /etc/passwd files and the ldap users.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `getent`, specifically `getent passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about [Change Password Utility (CPU)](http://cpu.sourceforge.net/) perhaps?

`cpu cat` should list all users in the LDAP directory.

Comment: To list users in /etc/passwd you could use `cat /etc/passwd`

Comment: not, i talk about list all network users and host users